# python Tix - how to clear a combobox

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tix

how do I clear all the items in a Tix.ComboBox object? I tried things like

```
cb.entry.delete (0, Tix.END)
```

and other veriations of this function
but it doesn't seem to do anything. also its not clear from the API which function I should use and the doc I've read say nothing about it. is it even possible??

thanks!

EDIT: PS deleting item by name will also be great. couldn't find how to do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tix.html#Tix.ComboBox) say, a ComboBox has an entry subwidget, and a listbox subwidget. See [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box) on combo boxes in general: the `Something else` part is the entry, and the `List item 1` etc. parts are the listbox.

So, `cb.entry.delete` is perfectly valid, but it's deleting the contents of the *entry* subwidget. That doesn't affect any of the items in the listbox.

---

So, how do you get the `listbox`? Well, in [Tcl/Tk](http://tix.sourceforge.net/dist/current/man/html/TixCmd/tixComboBox.htm), you can just access `cb.listbox`. But that doesn't work in Python/Tkinter.

If you look at [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/lib-tk/Tix.py#l564), you can see that `ComboBox` doesn't have two sub-widgets, but *five*, none of which is a `Listbox` or named `listbox`:

```
entry       Entry
arrow       Button
slistbox    ScrolledListBox
tick        Button
cross       Button : present if created with the fancy option
```

(You should be able to see this easily with `help(Tix.ComboBox)` in your interactive interpreter.)

But `ScrolledListBox` itself is *another* `Tix` composite widget, without anything useful on its own, so you still need to find the `Listbox` sub-sub-widget. Look at the help or [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/lib-tk/Tix.py#l1306) and it'll show you that `ScrolledListBox` has a `listbox`. Fortunately, that really *is* a `Listbox` (well, a `_dummyListbox`, but that's just a `Listbox` subclass that knows how to be a `Tix` subwidget).

So, what you *really* want is `cb.slistbox.listbox`.

(I believe that Tcl/Tk forwards along attribute references, while Python/Tkinter doesn't, which is why Tix and other fancy Tk wrappers and extensions aren't as nice to use from Python as the Tk docs make them appear.)

---

Note that, as the docs for `ListBox` say, `0` refers to the first entry, and `END` to the last entry, so the arguments in your call are correct.

So, long story short, this should do it:

```
cb.slistbox.listbox.delete(0, Tix.END)
```

And you should know how to find similar cases in the future. (Assuming you're not so traumatized by Tix that you avoid it completely.)

---

Meanwhile, as far as I know, there's no way to delete by name, but it's not that hard to do yourself. Just iterate the entries and check them:

```
for i in range(cb.slistbox.listbox.size()):
    if cb.slistbox.listbox.get(i) == name:
        cb.slistbox.listbox.delete(i)
        break
```

Comment: the combobox has no attribute listbox. are you sure this is the right way?

Comment: @Ness: That might be the wrong name (I don't have the Tix library on my system), but it's something close to this. (And accessing the `entry` is definitely _not_ the right way…) Let me look it up.

Comment: @Ness: The Tkinter docs for Tix are pretty sparse and just direct you to the Tcl/Tk docs for it. And [`tixComboBox`](http://tix.sourceforge.net/dist/current/man/html/TixCmd/tixComboBox.htm) definitely says it has a `listbox`. So, if that's not right… look at `dir(cb)` to see if there's anything that looks close, and meanwhile I'll look at the source for `Tix` quickly to see if I can see anything weird.

Comment: @Ness: Found it, I think. Try `slistbox`. Also, try `help(Tix.ComboBox)` in your interactive interpreter; it should make it pretty clear.

Comment: I tried dir and help before asking the question but dir doesn't show any of the subwidgets and apparently I missed this line in the help print: "slistbox ScrolledListBox" (that's all there is on this attribute). anyway slistbox don't have a 'delete' function (you might want to edit your answer). tbh this script is not that critical so meanwhile I just wrote an ugly function that destroy the entire combobox and recreate it in order to clear it.. thank you very much for your help though! :)